# How do l compare year of a date in xsl?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

How do I compare the year of a given date to int?

```
<if test="year(@varDate)>=1900">
true
</if>
```

Where the format of the date in the input file is:

```
<date varDate="31/12/1999" />
```

Comment: Please show us the XML input where the date is.

Comment: You tagged your question [tag:xslt-1.0], but your code shows `xs:gYear`, which is a constructor function of XSLT 2.0, did you mean to tag as [tag:xslt-2.0]?

Comment: Please show us the XML input where the date is and indicate whether using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 (makes a big difference in this case).

Comment: ok, I'm trying to figure out how to determine what version I'm using and will report back.

Comment: "*how to determine what version I'm using*" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033#25245033

Comment: You can find out what version your processor support by using `system-property('xsl:version')`, or by simply creating an XSLT 2.0 construct, i.e., set the version attribute to 2.0 and try to add `use-when="true()"` to any of your existing instructions. If you receive an error, you are on XSLT 1.0 (some XSLT 1.0 processors ignore the version attribute).

Comment: thank you, got the version and updated the tags. I'm using Microsoft. Ver. 1.0

Comment: Good. Well, all you need to do is to extract the year-part, then you can compare it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are stuck with XSLT 1.0, the most common way is to extract the year-part, like so:

```
substring-before('1994-12-31', '-')
```

Or, if your format is, let's say `dd/MM/yyyy`, you can do<sup>1</sup>:

```
substring-after('31/12/1999', '/')
```

In your case that would be something along those lines:

```
<xsl:if test="substring-after('31/12/1999', '/') > 1900">
    true
</xsl:if>
```

Since you didn't provide input data, I assume you can work out the details yourself. Your original question was tagged [xslt-1.0](/questions/tagged/xslt-1.0), but this has since changed. If that means that you can use XSLT 2.0 or higher, and you have an actual typed `xs:date` value, you can also use [`fn:year-from-date`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-year-from-date):

```
<xsl:if test="year-from-date(xs:date('1994-12-31')) > 1900">
    true
</xsl:if>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This is not enough as there are two slashes, use `substring-after(substring-after('31/12/1999', '/'), '/')`, as seen in [Michael's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32701096/111575) (credit to him).

Comment: In XSLT 1.0, converting to number is not required.

Comment: @Abel, so it turns out my date is in a different format that in solution above (dd/mm/yyyy). Any thoughts? Should I create a new post?

Comment: @Rod, simply change the expression to `substring-after(x, '/')`. I updated the answer (and your question ;).

Comment: thank you so much for the insight @Abel and everyone

Answer (score 1):

> it turns out my date is in a different format that in solution above
>   (dd/mm/yyyy).

If that's *really* your date format - i.e.both days and month are always padded to two digits - you can use:

```
<if test="substring(@varDate, 7) >= 1900">
```

as your test.

If not, you'll need:

```
<if test="substring-after(substring-after(@varDate, '/'), '/') >= 1900">
```